# Too many files to delete (rm) with wildcard in a shell script?

Tags: shell, rm

I have a shell script that needs to delete all of the files in a directory that start with a number. This file set has grown to contain hundreds of thousands of files that need to be deleted each day. The script contains the following lines:

```
rm -f /my/dir/11*
rm -f /my/dir/12*

(( etc ))

rm -f /my/dir/1*
rm -f /my/dir/2*
```

And I get the error message for every line

```
line 1: /usr/bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

I tried to replace the lines with

```
ls -d /my/dir/11* | xargs rm
```

but `ls -d` gives me the same error message.

How can I delete these files without growing the list to contain hundreds of filename permutations?

Comment: Which shell are you using? (`bash`? `ksh`? `zsh`? Something else?)

Comment: And what operating system? Do you have GNU tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get a relative path and pass it onto `rm`, you can use the `find` command, for your use case I'd run:

```
find /my/dir -iname '[0-9]*' -type f
```

That would return every file that start with a number. If that list is what you want to delete, have `find` delete them using `-delete`:

```
find /my/dir -iname '[0-9]*' -type f -delete
```

Good luck!

Comment: Of course you MUST `cd` into the desired folder if you don't want to do something catastrophic.

Comment: Using `-exec rm -f {} +` will probably be significantly faster, since it won't need to run one operation per file.

Comment: Bad habit of mine, @roaima. I'll edit the answer!

Comment: Not breaking out a `rm` subprocess and instead using `-delete` would be even faster.

Comment: `find ... -delete` isn't POSIX, so `find ... -exec rm -f {} +` might be necessary for some implementations

Comment: Does not the pattern '[0-9]*' match ZERO numerics, and therefore delete every file in the directory tree ?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant when used with `-name` or `-iname`, it's a glob not a regex, so it matches filenames that start with a decimal digit

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for ELI70. The -iname threw me too, as we are not matching any text, so -name suffices. TIL fnmatch() too.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell has a built-in `printf` command (e. g. Bash or Dash) it likely accepts longer argument lists which you can pipe to `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\0' /path/to/glob* | xargs -0 rm -f
```